# Get the values from an array string to work with post__in

Tags: array

> Basically i need help to build a proper array to pass as
>   value of `post__in`

Basically code has to get featured images of posts **only for selected ids**. I need your help to extract the values of the concerned array string in the right manner as currently the code gives a warning `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in .../..`. It still displays images though. The issue is it displays images from across all posts instead of **images only from posts with selected ids**, as intended.

```
 $sel_ids = $_SESSION['selected_ids'];

 global $wpdb; 
 require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');

 $args = array('post__in' => implode( ', ', $sel_ids ), 'post_type' => 'post');   
 $posts = get_posts($args);

 foreach ($posts as $post) {
     echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'coverimage');
 }
```

In the first line of code block above, this string `$sel_ids` carries ids of selected posts. When `echoed` gives `Array`. When `var_dump($sel_ids)` shows

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "67" [1]=> string(2) "16" }
```

and `foreach` gives a string such as `6716`. I do not need the `foreach` in my code but giving additional info so that it may help you infer better. The code above is not on a template page, but instead on a separate page.  it is actually a form-processor. I need the code to run here as I need to grab those values and email them later. So I have loaded WordPress globals. The session is there to carry array value from the form.

---

UPDATE - @Mamaduka - Here is a relevant part of the source of the email in gmail

```
Array<img src="http://xxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/360.jpg">
```

Comment: "The code below is not on a template page, but instead on a separate page" please explain what is separate page. And why are you using sessions.

Comment: Well, args isn't a proper variable, you're missing "$". You can also try creating a variable to hold the imploded string for later use, rather than trying to use it in the array itself. ie. $post_string = implode(', ', $sel_ids');

Comment: You should check with `is_array()` before implode. Also use `has_post_thumbnail()` in condition before try to echo post thumbnail. And fix `args` to `$args` :)

Comment: `post__in` should receive an array, not a string.

Comment: What happens when you just echo $post_string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is that, `post_in` accepts only array of post IDs and `implode()` returns string.

Here's how fixed code should look like (also added few conditional checks):

```
$sel_ids = $_SESSION['selected_ids'];

/**
 * Check, if we have array of Post IDs
 */
if ( ! is_array( $sel_ids ) ) {
    return;
}

require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');

$args = array( 'post__in' => $sel_ids, 'post_type' => 'post' );
$posts = get_posts($args);

if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
    return;
}

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'coverimage');
}
```

Comment: That is correct, looks like I jumped through hoops for nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Although it works now, this line `$args = array( 'post__in' => $sel_ids, 'post_type' => 'post' );` seems to html output the word `Array` which is odd. Any ideas to avoid that.

Comment: @gurung can you link the screenshot here, source code of  the HTML output would be best.

Comment: The output is a part of an email so I grabbed this from the source of the email in gmail.Please look at the UPDATE in the bottom of the question. Also I have asked this as a new question.

Comment: Also I have asked in a [new question here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145322/post-in-works-but-also-prints-the-word-array). If possible please answer there.